# Nested Routes : Couldn't find Course with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with my models and controllers. I can't find the right sourcing to have a good nested routing.
I have three models:

- `Courses` (has_many :chapters)
- `Chapters` (belongs_to :course)
- and `Items` (belongs_to :chapter).

In the folder `config/routes.rb` I tried to nest the following models:

```
get 'courses/:id' => 'courses#show', as: :courses_show do 
    get 'chapters/show' do 
        get 'items/show' 
    end
end
```

[image: Source]

But it sends an error when I try to see the Chapter view:

> Couldn't find Course with 'id'= for chapters and items.

[image]

I am a bit lost, any thoughts?

Comment: You are setting your resources wrong, see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources. That alone would probably solve your issue.

Comment: could you run `rake routes` or go to localhost:3000/rails/routes and paste the routes that are being generated here?

Comment: Here are the routes from rake routes @surya
   courses GET      /courses(.:format)                     courses#index courses_show GET      /courses/:id(.:format)                 courses#show
  chapters_show GET      /chapters/show(.:format)               chapters#show
     items_show GET      /items/show(.:format)                  items#show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:

```
resources :courses, only: [:show] do
  resources  :chapters, only: [:show] do
    resources :items, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Igor I do that                                                                                               # resources :courses, only [:show] do
    # resources :chapters, only [:show] do
      # resources :items, only [:show]
    # end
  # end                                                                                                                   But there s a syntax errors: "syntax error, unexpected [, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  resources :courses, only [:show] do"

Comment: it's good! i'll edit my answer with solution, maybe it'll be useful for somebody  else

Comment: You will! I think it's fundamental!